# Unable to decode json in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

Here is my JSON string which is returned from servlet

```
[{"label":"AGARTALA","value":"50514"},{"label":"AGRA","value":"50312"},{"label":"AHMEDABAD","value":"50214"}]
```

I am trying to get it javascript Hashmap as

```
var jsonBranches=$.parseJSON('${questionBeanCV.branches}');
```

However on alert of jsonBranches i get

```
 jsonBranches=[object Object],[object Object],....,[object Object]
```

I want jsonBranches as Hashmap.

How can i do that ?

Comment: Did you try: console.log of jsonBranches?

Comment: What you have is an array. What kind of "Hashmap" do you want ?

Comment: there are no hashmaps in javascript.

Comment: @Christoph Arguable. Objects can be used to work a lot like hashmaps

Answer (score 1):

[JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) is the function that you are looking for.

Try,

```
alert(JSON.stringify(jsonBranches));
```

Comment: however downvoted this is wrong.

Comment: How is that supposed to help get a hashmap ?

Comment: stringify is for **seralising an object** to JSON, not for parsing a JSON string.

Comment: @dystroy You need to stringify objects, before passing them to `alert` .

Comment: The problem isn't even parsing : OP wants to get a map from his already parsed array.

Comment: @dystroy OP has a string, parses it and does not know why it didn't seem to work. This however is not the fault of the parseJSON not working but, the alert doing toString "incorrectly".

Comment: @Christoph What do you do with the question ? *"I am trying to get it javascript Hashmap"*. But this question is rather fuzzy, I voted to close.

Comment: @dystroy JS has no hashmaps, but only objects (which are basically the same). THe OP was just confused by the incorrect output from alert I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON string is correctly parsed, and yelds an *array*, not a object.

Guess you want something like:

```
{"AGARTALA" : "50514", "AGRA" : "50312" ... }
```

In this case, you have to process the result on your own, like for instance:

```
var result = {};

$.each(jsonBranches, function(index, item){ result[item.label] = item.value;  });
```